# How to create a PKCS#7 detached signature with .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, bouncycastle, pkcs#7

I want to create PKCS#7 detached signature with .Net Core (2.0).

I read all answers here more or less relevant to my issue and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346009/detached-pkcs7-cms-with-strong-private-key-protection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779669/create-a-pkcs7-signed-message-in-c-sharp-with-a-precomputed-signature) answers. All other were helpless. The first example do exactly what I need but it relies on .NetFramework.
The second one use Bouncy Castle library and do little different but similar thing. I found [Portable.BouncyCastle](https://github.com/onovotny/bc-csharp) project worked on  .Net Core. As I can understand it is the only option for me.

This is the code from the first example with some modifications:

```
    string s = "data string";
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);        
    X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
    X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My,StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    certificate = my.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "my thumbprint", false)[0];
    if (certificate == null) throw new Exception("No certificates found.");

    ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.1"),data);
    SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(content, true);

    CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(certificate);
    signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("SHA256"); 

    // create the signature
    signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
    return signedCms.Encode();
```

It works fine in my case.  signedCms.Encode() returns 1835 bytes and this value pass validation.

But if I use BounceCastle I get another result. This is the code:

```
                X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
        X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        certificate = my.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "my thumbprint", false)[0];
        var privKey = DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey()).Private;
        var cert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificate);

        var content = new CmsProcessableByteArray(data);

        var generator = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();

        generator.AddSigner(privKey, cert, CmsSignedGenerator.EncryptionRsa, CmsSignedGenerator.DigestSha256);

        var signedContent = generator.Generate(content, false);
        return signedContent.GetEncoded();
```

signedContent.GetEncoded() returns 502 bytes and this result can't be validated. I understand that I'm doing wrong something but I don't know what.

How should I modify the sample with Bouncy Castle that it get me the same result as the code above?

Comment: You are not specifying the Oid when using CmsSignedDataGenerator, may this be why?

Comment: For what it's worth: SignedCms was added to .NET Core for 2.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an another [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779669/create-a-pkcs7-signed-message-in-c-sharp-with-a-precomputed-signature) that gave me a clue. There is a link to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jariq/Pkcs7SignatureGenerator/tree/master/src/Pkcs7SignatureGenerator) with an example application. I modified it slightly and now it works as expected. Here is the code:

```
            X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
        X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        certificate = my.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "thumbprint", false)[0];
        var privKey = DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey()).Private;
        var cert = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(certificate);

        var content = new CmsProcessableByteArray(data);

        var generator = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();

        generator.AddSigner(privKey, cert, CmsSignedGenerator.EncryptionRsa, CmsSignedGenerator.DigestSha256);

        var signedContent = generator.Generate(content, false);

        string hashOid = OID.SHA256;

        var si = signedContent.GetSignerInfos();
        var signer = si.GetSigners().Cast<SignerInformation>().First();

        SignerInfo signerInfo = signer.ToSignerInfo();

        Asn1EncodableVector digestAlgorithmsVector = new Asn1EncodableVector();
        digestAlgorithmsVector.Add(
            new AlgorithmIdentifier(
                algorithm: new DerObjectIdentifier(hashOid),
                parameters: DerNull.Instance));

        // Construct SignedData.encapContentInfo
        ContentInfo encapContentInfo = new ContentInfo(
            contentType: new DerObjectIdentifier(OID.PKCS7IdData),
            content: null);

        Asn1EncodableVector certificatesVector = new Asn1EncodableVector();
        certificatesVector.Add(X509CertificateStructure.GetInstance(Asn1Object.FromByteArray(cert.GetEncoded())));

        // Construct SignedData.signerInfos
        Asn1EncodableVector signerInfosVector = new Asn1EncodableVector();
        signerInfosVector.Add(signerInfo.ToAsn1Object());

        // Construct SignedData
        SignedData signedData = new SignedData(
            digestAlgorithms: new DerSet(digestAlgorithmsVector),
            contentInfo: encapContentInfo,
            certificates: new BerSet(certificatesVector),
            crls: null,
            signerInfos: new DerSet(signerInfosVector));

        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(
            contentType: new DerObjectIdentifier(OID.PKCS7IdSignedData),
            content: signedData);

        return contentInfo.GetDerEncoded();
```